# Can't get Freeradius2 to send logs to syslog-ng version 3.5

Tags: logging, syslog-ng, freeradius2, centralized-logging

I have a Syslog-ng 3.5 and freeradius2 Ubuntu server 16.04 both running as virtual machines in a vmware esxi 5.5 HYpervisor.

Well from a previous [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/845134/freeradius-not-redirecting-logs-to-syslog-ng) I got sylog-ng to send logs from /var/log/fereradius/radius.log directory to a remote syslog-ng server,

The problem is I have almost no space left in the freeradius server.

And I made these changes to the radiusd.conf file in /etc/freeradius/ directory

```
1---logdir=syslog

2---destination=syslog

3---syslog_facility=daemon
```

But Still no luck in making this speaks with the syslog-ng client in the same machine which sends the logs to the remote syslog-ng server.

I have looked in the forums and in the syslog wiki but still does not work, I check with `netstat -tunlp` but do not see the local connection from the freeradius server to the syslog-ng server. 
I checked with `nc -uv [IP-LOCAL-SYSLOG-SERVER] 514` and got a successful connection to the local syslog-ng server (So is listening in the 514 udp port).Any light on this?. Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set log.destination to syslog, i.e. the `destination` option within the `log {}` section.

https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v2.x.x/raddb/radiusd.conf.in#L409

Comment: I already made that was point 2. That' s what seems strage to me that after making those 3 changes to the config file,and restarted the service, nothing.

Comment: one question, having set all that (logdir = syslog, destination = syslog and syslog_facility = daemon ) it doesn' t suppose that freeradius tries to connect to localhost using UDP as transport and port 514  via syslog protocol ?

Comment: It calls the syslog() function which usually results in the message being written to a predetermined unix socket, which is picked up by the syslog daemon.

destination != log.destination, many of the config items were placed in sections in the transition from v1.x.x->2.x.x.  It's important to qualify config items with their parent sections.